# Custom filter for grid view not working: Couldn't find with 'id'=all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using wice_grid and have defined a custom filter for two associated models, following the [instruction](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#custom-filters-and-associations-joined-tables) of the gem. I have:

```
g.column name: 'Organization', filter_type: :string, attribute: 'name', model: 'Organization', auto_reload: true, html: {id: 'grid-cells'},
         custom_filter: Organization.find(:all).map{|pr| [pr.name, pr.name]} do |user|
  link_to(user.organization.name, organization_path(user.organization))
end
```

This generates the error:

```
Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=all
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Organization.all`. `find(:all)` is deprecated in latest version of rails

Comment: Yes, that works! Did generate another problem (might post a new question?). That is, even though I've added `filter_type: :string` the filter it shows is a drop-down box with all existing organizations. I would like a text search box instead. Also using `filter_type: :text` makes no difference. https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#filters

Comment: If it solves your current problem please accept the answer. and post your new problem as another question. @Nick